# Is it possible to make discussion questions on WorldBuilding.SE?

Tags: discussion, on-topic

Is it possible to make discussion questions in WorldBuilding.SE?

**If I have a question where I need a suggestion or a discussion, is there a place to post it?**

It would be great if we could have a place to argue about WorldBuilding, or a place to ask for suggestions or ideas.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is already such a place, and we call it:

[The Factory Floor](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17213/the-factory-floor)

Stackexchange offers a whole chat solution hosted under: http://chat.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thank, but how does it work? I mean, it is a chat, how does we choose about what to discuss? Sorry, I an not very familiarized with chats.

Comment: @EnderLook you click on the link to the factory floor and then bring up the thing you'd like to discuss. If someone has time to join or help they will join your discussion. Pretty much like it works with questions. It's just less formal :)

Comment: @enderlook Go to the chat and ask your question or whatever it is you want to talk about. At the moment there aren't many people in chat but people are usually more than wiling to discuss it with you.

Comment: @dot_Sp0T and much more flexible.